# jquery mobile function calling two times

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using change page event in jquery mobile with multiview plugin when page is change the function calling two times means if am using alert it shows same alert two times and when I click on back button some it shows the page but when I do this frequently it shows error in plug in file   can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the `pagebeforechange` event?
This event is triggering twice as designed.
The difference between this two calls is the data's `toPage` attribute:

```
jQuery(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
    var toPage = data.toPage;
    if(typeof toPage === 'string') {
        // -- triggered first
        // -- toPage is a string containing the page`s url
    } else {
        // -- triggered second
        // -- toPage is an jQuery collection object containing the page
    }
});
```